# "@" in A Record of DNS setting, blank or everything?

Tags: domain-name-system

Usually I use "*" in A Record and let Apache+Nginx handle the incoming requests. However today I added a CDN service thus routed most of the requests directy to the CDN sever except two sub-domain for backup purposes.

While waiting for the new settings to be promoted, I am kind of wondering how does this "@" act in A Record? Does it equivalent to "blank" (eg, domian.com,) or as "*"(eg, *.domian.com).

Comment: I think I know the answer should be "blank". Part of the reason why i asked this question at the first place is that the visiting speed via CDN(which locates at the other side of the Pacific) is actually faster than w/o it(the data center contains my vps is in less 100 miles.) Put asides all my hard work on optimizing and caching..the CDN at the other side of the ocean beats me?!

Comment: Just to note, "blank" does not equate to "domain.com", a blank entry for the first field causes the DNS server (BIND at least) to use the same value as the entry above. Also the origin can be changed in a zone file using the `$ORIGIN` variable so it is possible that `@` might not map to the domain name. If you look at an automatically generated BIND slave zone file, they make quite heavy use of `$ORIGIN` to keep the first field short and help reduce the size of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an indication that the record applies to the origin of the zone data.  So, if the origin of your zone is `example.com`, a record `@ IN A 192.0.2.1` will translate to `example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1`.  No wildcards will be involved and this is not a wildcard record.